# Issue with logic in PHP palindrome challenge

Tags: php, if-statement

As part of an interview I was challenged with debugging the following php script. I will first provide the original broken code.  Then what I did to debug it followed with my attempt to fix the logic.

```
<?php

/**
 * Class Palindrome
 */
class Palindrome {

    /**
     * Sting that will be parsed for palindrome.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $string;

    /**
     * Handle.
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        do {
            $this->getInput();

            if ($this->string === 'exit') {
                echo "Goodbye!";
                exit;
            }

            $palindromes = $this->findPalindromes();
            $this->formatOutput($palindromes);
        } while (true);
    }

    /**
     * Get input from user.
     */
    private function getInput()
    {
        echo "Input: ";
        $this->string = rtrim(fgets(STDIN));
    }

    /**
     * Format string to desired output.
     *
     * @param $palindromes
     * @return string
     */
    private function formatOutput($palindromes)
    {
        $foundString = '';
        $palindromeCount = count($palindromes);

        foreach ($palindromes as $palindrome) {
            $foundString .= ', ' . $palindrome;
        }

        echo "This string contains {$palindromeCount} palindrome words (i.e.{$foundString})" . PHP_EOL;
    }

    /**
     * Determines if the given string
     * contains palindromes.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function findPalindromes()
    {
        $palindromes = [];
        $words = explode(" ",$this->string);

        foreach ($words as $word) {
            $characters = str_split(strtolower($word));
            $charCount = count($characters);
            $palindromeFound = $word;

            for ($leftIndex = 0; $leftIndex < $charCount; $leftIndex++) {
                $rightIndex = (int) ($charCount) - $leftIndex;

                if ($characters[$leftIndex] = $characters[$rightIndex]) {
                    $palindromeFound = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            ($palindromeFound) ? $palindromes[] = $palindromeFound: null
        }

        return $palindroms;
    }
}


$class = new Palindrome();

$class->handle();
```

In addition to fixing some typos I updated the value on line 76 to 1, and line 80 to true.  The code runs without error but thinks everything is a palindrome.

```
<?php

/**
 * Class Palindrome
 */
class Palindrome {

    /**
     * Sting that will be parsed for palindrome.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $string;

    /**
     * Handle.
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        do {
            $this->getInput();

            if ($this->string === 'exit') {
                echo "Goodbye!";
                exit;
            }

            $palindromes = $this->findPalindromes();
            $this->formatOutput($palindromes);
        } while (true);
    }

    /**
     * Get input from user.
     */
    private function getInput()
    {
        echo "Input: ";
        $this->string = rtrim(fgets(STDIN));
    }

    /**
     * Format string to desired output.
     *
     * @param $palindromes
     * @return string
     */
    private function formatOutput($palindromes)
    {
        $foundString = '';
        $palindromeCount = count($palindromes);

        foreach ($palindromes as $palindrome) {
            $foundString .= ', ' . $palindrome;
        }

        echo "This string contains {$palindromeCount} palindrome words (i.e.{$foundString})" . PHP_EOL;
    }

    /**
     * Determines if the given string
     * contains palindromes.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function findPalindromes()
    {
        $palindromes = [];
        $words = explode(" ",$this->string);

        foreach ($words as $word) {
            $characters = str_split(strtolower($word));
            $charCount = count($characters);
            $palindromeFound = $word;

            for ($leftIndex = 1; $leftIndex < $charCount; $leftIndex++) {
                $rightIndex = (int) ($charCount) - $leftIndex;

                if ($characters[$leftIndex] = $characters[$rightIndex]) {
                    $palindromeFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            ($palindromeFound) ? $palindromes[] = $palindromeFound: null;
        }

        return $palindromes;
    }
}


$class = new Palindrome();

$class->handle();
```

My attempt at correcting the logic was to add an elseif on line 82. However I am still getting the same consistently wrong output.

```
<?php

/**
 * Class Palindrome
 */
class Palindrome {

    /**
     * Sting that will be parsed for palindrome.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $string;

    /**
     * Handle.
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        do {
            $this->getInput();

            if ($this->string === 'exit') {
                echo "Goodbye!";
                exit;
            }

            $palindromes = $this->findPalindromes();
            $this->formatOutput($palindromes);
        } while (true);
    }

    /**
     * Get input from user.
     */
    private function getInput()
    {
        echo "Input: ";
        $this->string = rtrim(fgets(STDIN));
    }

    /**
     * Format string to desired output.
     *
     * @param $palindromes
     * @return string
     */
    private function formatOutput($palindromes)
    {
        $foundString = '';
        $palindromeCount = count($palindromes);

        foreach ($palindromes as $palindrome) {
            $foundString .= ', ' . $palindrome;
        }

        echo "This string contains {$palindromeCount} palindrome words (i.e.{$foundString})" . PHP_EOL;
    }

    /**
     * Determines if the given string
     * contains palindromes.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function findPalindromes()
    {
        $palindromes = [];
        $words = explode(" ",$this->string);

        foreach ($words as $word) {
            $characters = str_split(strtolower($word));
            $charCount = count($characters);
            $palindromeFound = $word;

            for ($leftIndex = 1; $leftIndex < $charCount; $leftIndex++) {
                $rightIndex = (int) ($charCount) - $leftIndex;

                if ($characters[$leftIndex] = $characters[$rightIndex]) {
                    $palindromeFound = true;

                    }elseif ($characters[$leftIndex] <> $characters[$rightIndex]) {
                    $palindromeFound = false;


                    break;
                }
            }

            ($palindromeFound) ? $palindromes[] = $palindromeFound: null;
        }

        return $palindromes;
    }
}


$class = new Palindrome();

$class->handle();
```

Comment: Always use == without using = in an if statement

Comment: _line 82..._ Which one is 82?

Comment: line 79 (original) has an assignment operator, should have `===` or at least `==` https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: That was it!  I had to eliminate the elseif and change operator to ===